# NSOpenPanel breaks my SDL/OpenGL app

Tags: cocoa, opengl, sdl

I'm making a small SDL/OpenGL game, in which the user can select a map/level by using the cocoa open file-dialog (NSOpenPanel). However, when doing so, I get the error "invalid frame-buffer operation" upon every glClear. When I get the status of the frame buffer (using glCheckFramebufferStatus) it's GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED (0x8219). I also noticed that I do not need to present the open panel (using runModal), but only to create it, for the error to occur. It is possible to create it before the SDL_SetVideoMode, but not thereafter. Strangely, the NSSavePanel doesn't cause these issues at all. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Added some code to show a stripped down test-init method:

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
m_pScreen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 800, 600, 32, SDL_OPENGL );

// this section causes the problem. Works well if I change the NSOpenPanel to a NSSavePanel
@autoreleasepool {
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel openPanel] retain];    
    [openPanel runModal];
    [openPanel release];
}

int number = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); 
assert(number == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE); // crash here
```

Comment: can you show some code to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Updated the post with my current init code.

Comment: I'm having the exact same as you're having. It started suddenly. A few minutes ago that wasn't happening and I havent changed my code.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens because there's no current context. The OS-supplied code like `NSOpenPanel` can sometimes change the current OpenGL context, or leave the current context as undefined. You must make sure that you set the context back to the one you're drawing to when this happens. I hit this same problem in some code I'm working on last week! :-)

Comment: Yes, this is the reason behind the issue. I've made a new answer with the fix/code.

Answer (score 2):

After some more testing (and reading the previous answers) I found a solution which works for me:

```
@autoreleasepool    {
NSOpenGLContext *foo = [NSOpenGLContext currentContext];
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel runModal];
[foo makeCurrentContext];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To work around this oddity I had to reset my view with SDL_SetVideoMode if frame buffer status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE